# How to align my flexbox items in proper way?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to figure out how to align my flexbox items. I'm not sure if it's even possible so I'm asking. Here is my code:
my css:

```
.container {width: 100%; display: flex; position: relative;}
.item {display: flex;}
.one {width: 65%;}
.two {width: 35%;}
```

and the html:

```
<div class="container>
<div class="item one"></div>
<div class="item one"></div>
<div class="item one"></div>
<div class="item two"></div>
<div class="item two"></div>
</div>
```

and i'd like to make it like that:
[image: sheet]

Answer (score 1):

You want `flex-direction: column` and `flex-wrap:wrap`. Then give your items heights so they wrap inside the container vertically:

```css
html,body{height:100%;}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: solid 2px orangered;
  width: 50%;
  height: 60%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.item {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin: 2px;
}

.one {
  height: calc(33% - 4px);
  border: solid 2px green;
  width: calc(65% - 4px);
}

.two {
  height: 40%;
  border: solid 2px orange;
  width: calc(35% - 4px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class=" item one ">one</div>
  <div class="item one ">one</div>
  <div class="item one ">one</div>
  <div class="item two ">two</div>
  <div class="item two ">two</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks,that looks interesting but i would like to have the "one" column 65% wide and the "two" column 35% to fill whole container, can you give me the solution?

Comment: @qRx. just add the widths in (see my edit). The only trick is to use `calc()` to account for the 2px margin, and give the .container a `box-sizing: border-box`

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/) you can find a quick example of how flexbox works. It is very useful if you are beginner.